# Need a script to send an email without resending to previously recorded senders

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the script below which I modified from an existing sendEmail script.  I am collecting information from a Google Form and wish to send the email with each "Submit".  The problem I am having is that the script sends to every row of the spreadsheet even though that information was already sent.  I need the script to somehow mark the row sent so that the information cannot be resent.  My "newbie" way around this was to have the email address changed to my email address after sending.  I filtered my inbox to automatically delete these emails.  That is my crude solution, but I would like it to work correctly.  Any suggestions, please?

```
 var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

    function sendEmails() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 17);

      var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
      var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
        var rowData = objects[i];

    // Generate a personalized email.
    // Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
    // the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
        var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
        var emailSent = rowData[4];
        if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
          var emailSubject = "CCSS Walkthrough";
          MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText);
          var startRow = 2;
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 2).setValue("myemailaddress");
          SpreadsheetApp.flush ();
    }
   } 
}


// Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
// Arguments:
//   - template: string containing markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
//   - data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
//           data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
// Returns a string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker, it is
// simply removed.
    function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
      var email = template;
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
      var templateVars = template.match(/\${\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);

  // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
  // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
      for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
    // normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
        var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i])];
        email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
  }

      return email;
}





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
    function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
      columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
      var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
      var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1,       numColumns);
      var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
      return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
    function getObjects(data, keys) {
      var objects = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var object = {};
        var hasData = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
          var cellData = data[i][j];
          if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
            continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
    function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
      var keys = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
        var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
        if (key.length > 0) {
          keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
    function normalizeHeader(header) {
      var key = "";
      var upperCase = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
        var letter = header[i];
        if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
          upperCase = true;
          continue;
    }
        if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
          continue;
    }
        if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
          continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
        if (upperCase) {
          upperCase = false;
          key += letter.toUpperCase();
    }     else {
          key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
    function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
      return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
    function isAlnum(char) {
       return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
        char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
        isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise. 
    function isDigit(char) {
      return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to add a column and mark it email_sent and then filter those out when sending.

[Section 2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section2) of [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) does exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

This method allows you to retain the email address of the person that submitted the form.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you want to do is: " *I am collecting information from a Google Form and wish to send the email with each "Submit".*" You don't really even have to access the spreadsheet to send the information you want to send. The spreadsheet will actually store the information that came with the Form submit but you don't have to go back to the spreadsheet to send the data to an email on submit. You can instead write a function that is triggered at Form Submit, which will take in the form submit as an event and grab the relevant data from there and send it to the desired email address. I am including a demo code here, check the comments for more detials.

```
function onFormSubmit(event) { //On form submission send an email to the approver.
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     //Get values that have to be put on the email.
     //event.values[index] is indexed in the same order that form values are ordered        on the spreadhseet
var formVal1 = event.values[0]; 
var formVal2 = event.values[1];
.
.
.
.
. 
var  formValN = event.values[N];
//Setting the message that goes on the email sent to the approver.
var message = 'This message has the following information from the form submit: '+ formVal1+'blah blah' + formVal2+...........+formValN;
//Title for the mail sent.
var title = 'New Submission';
//Email address the email is sent to.
var mailAdd = 'example@receiveemail.com' //this could be an array for multiple recipients.
//Sending Email.   
MailApp.sendEmail(mailAdd, title, message);
}
```

After this script is written up you have to go to **Resources>Current script's triggers**. In that let your function be triggered from the spreadsheet on Form Submit.